# Devil May Cry game order

Tags: devil-may-cry-series

As Humble Bundle currently offers a discount on many DmC games, I looked into getting them all. Though it proved hard to get the right games. This is mostly caused by the reboot.

I found following infos on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devil_May_Cry):

[image]

[image]

This info sadly misses the fact which games are replaced by "Devil May Cry HD Collection". Through some googling I found that the HD collection includes DmC 1, DmC 2 and DmC 3. So my understanding would be, that if I want to get the whole story game wise, I would need to get following games:

1. Devil May Cry HD Collection
2. Devil May Cry 4
3. Devil May Cry 5

and then play them in the order listed in the second picture.

**Is that assumption correct or am I missing something?**

Comment: The reboot's gameplay is decent, but the rest of the game is absolutely horrendous (lore/characters/story, etc.)
Otherwise, DMC2 is widely regarded as the worst of the series as well, and the story is pretty much completely unrelated to the other games, so feel free to skip it if you hate it. Your list is indeed all your need IMO, have fun!

Answer (score 7):

The proper order is as follows

- Devil May Cry 3
- Devil May Cry 1
- Devil May Cry 2
- Devil May Cry 4
- Devil May Cry 5

Devil May Cry 2 is pretty unrelated to the rest although one character is mentioned in Devil May Cry 5

DMC: Devil May Cry is entirely unreleated to the series storywise and is simply a reboot.

Comment: So wikipedias chronoligical order is wrong? And the listed games I'd need to buy is correct?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I was mistaken as to where 2 went in the timeline, but as it is of little relevance to the general story it doesn't really matter, So yes your list is correct.

Answer (score 1):

It goes 3, 1, the anime, 2, 4, 5.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade. What you wrote is already covered by the other ansewer.

Comment: I would say the answerer added info about animation which the other answer did not mention, but well, it works better as comment, I guess.